# Flutter app crash: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, lldb

> ```
> Process 94697 stopped
> * thread #8, name = 'io.flutter.1.ui', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
> frame #0: 0x000000010c1ae5a7 
> Flutter`dart::LocalScope::AllocateVariables(dart::VariableIndex, int, 
> dart::VariableIndex, dart::LocalScope*, bool*) + 135
> Flutter`dart::LocalScope::AllocateVariables:
> ```

App crashes on iOS, but works perfectly on android

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: same issue very cryptic message

Answer (score 0):

In my case this solves my issue:

Xcode -> Product -> Clean Build Folder

Hope to help someone.